# How to edit quantity display on Magento checkout page

Tags: magento

I have added a extension that can be found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33997/#t197176

It adds a quantity box to the checkbox option on bundle products.

This issue is that no matter what the user enters in the quantity box, it displays as 1 X product (does not display the user defined quantity).  I can't figure out where the code is that I need to change in the shopping cart to pull the correct quantity.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  Even if it is just where the code is that defines that quantity in the cart.  Magento ver. 1.6.2.0

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the extension and it looks like the template mods are in `/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/` by default.

Copy `/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml` to `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml`  (or into your current theme's path - like `/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME`).

hth

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by editing item.phtml (template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml) and these lines after line no #47

```
<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>   
    <td class="a-center">
        <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" name="update_cart_action" id="cup_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"  class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
    </td>
   <td> <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('shopping-cart-table'); ?>" id="up_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></span></span></button><td>
```

and put Jquery code at the end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".btn-update").click(function(){


        var id = "#c"+this.id;
        var quan = jQuery(id).val();
        var lastChar = id.substr(id.length - 1);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>checkout/cart/updatePosts/",
            data: "cart["+lastChar+"][qty]="+quan,
            async: false,
                success: function(html){

                    location.reload();

                }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

now override cartcontroller.php and place all the functions of the original cartcontroller.php and rename function updatePostAction by function updatePostsAction.
and change the redirect path to `$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');`